# asp.net OnClick events for controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I'm converting a VB project to C#, and I notice that in vb it will call a function like:

```
 Protected Sub WZTestResult_NextButtonClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.WizardNavigationEventArgs) Handles WZTestResult.NextButtonClick
```

which handles the next button click event for a wizard.

In c# I have to add the line:

```
 OnNextButtonClick="WZTestResult_NextButtonClick"
```

on the asp.net source page or it will never hit the function.  Is this a necessity in c#, or is there something that I'm overlooking or missing?  Basically, is there a way in c# for it to hit that function like in VB without adding the line above in the source page?

Comment: Nope: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t367616-using-handles-vb-vs-c.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent for VB's Handles keyword.

You can do it in code behind if you want, when the page is initialized

```
public Default() {

    this.Init += (_o, _e) => {
         this.Wizard.NextButtonClick += WZTestResult_NextButtonClick;
    }
}
```

Default is the page constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking the IDE will take care of most of this for you. If you add a button to a form in the Visual Studio designer and double click on that button it will take you to the event handler for that control in the code (the click event in this case).

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

You'll notice that the file you're in doesn't contain the code that attaches this method to the control event. Visual Studio splits the form into a partial class that contains your code and a generated class that contains auto-generated wiring code. In the solution explorer that looks like this:

Form1.cs  -> the file that you'll add code to
Form1.Designer.cs   -> the auto-generated designer file

You don't want to change the .designer.cs files because changing the form in the visual designer might overwrite your changes. You'll just work in the Form1.cs file and you'll likely never even see the event assignment code.

So the answer to your question is no, with the caveat that you'll rarely ever have to add or see this code:

```
this.Wizard.NextButtonClick += WZTestResult_NextButtonClick;
```